# Bootstrap 4 remove div on MD and below

Tags: bootstrap-4

I have a div that have a complate different content structure on MD, SM, XS.
So I have 2 divs. 1 div for LG and XL and 1 seperate div for MD, SM, XS.

hiding and show the divs with display propery `d-none d-md-block` works great but div is still appearing in source.

problem is: i have values attached to ID's. So if there are 2 DIV's in source it does not show the content because of multiple ID's.

Question: Is there a possibility/solution on BS4 to hide/remove a element that is not showing up in frontend?

Here are the 2 DIV's

```
   <div class="d-lg-flex d-xl-flex align-items-center diverse-angaben d-none d-md-block">
        <div class="container d-flex">
            <p class="no-padding mr-3">Wunschkredit: <strong>CHF&nbsp;</strong><span id="kredit" class="fett">36000</span></p>
            <p class="no-padding mr-3">Laufzeit: <span id="laufzeit" class="fett">120</span><strong>&nbsp;Monate</strong></p>
            <p class="no-padding">Monatliche Rate zwischen:&nbsp;<span id="out1" class="fett">378.33</span><strong>&nbsp;und&nbsp;</strong><span id="out2" class="fett">469.78</span><strong>&nbsp;</strong></p>
        </div>
    </div>




    <div class="d-lg-flex d-xl-flex align-items-center angaben-mobile">
        <div class="container d-flex">
            <div role="tablist" id="accordion-1">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header bg-white border-white shadow-none" role="tab">
                        <h5 class="mb-0"><a data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="accordion-1 .item-1" href="#accordion-1 .item-1">Kreditangaben&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a></h5>
                    </div>
                    <div class="collapse show item-1 bg-light shadow-lg" role="tabpanel" data-parent="#accordion-1">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <p class="no-padding mr-3">Wunschkredit: <strong>CHF&nbsp;</strong><span id="kredit-1" class="fett">36000</span></p>
                            <p class="no-padding mr-3">Laufzeit: <span id="laufzeit-1" class="fett">120</span><strong>&nbsp;Monate</strong></p>
                            <p class="no-padding">Monatliche Rate:&nbsp;<span id="out-1" class="fett">378.33</span><strong>&nbsp;und&nbsp;</strong><span id="out-2" class="fett">469.78</span><strong>&nbsp;</strong></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Could you give a code snippet?

Comment: edited the main post